# Proper way of using file_get_contents() PHP function

Tags: php, curl, error-handling, file-get-contents

I have some troubles with `file_get_contents()` function: if the remote file redirected to another URI I get script interruption and repetition of script output:

Code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(['http'=>['timeout'=>10]]);
$url = 'http://example.com/';
echo "URL: $url\n";
$page = file_get_contents($url,FALSE,$context);
echo "Page size: ".strlen($page);
```

Output:

```
URL: http://example.com/
URL: http://example.com/
```

(make note that the output duplicated and there are no "Page size" output)

Expected output:

```
URL: http://example.com/
Page size: 1000
```

I believe that `file_get_contents()` can not handle the redirect that I can see if I'd try my URL in a browser. So I'd like to achieve one of the following:

1. Catch the error to be able to handle the situation
2. Load the page despite the redirect

Maybe I can add more options to `$context`? Or the **only** way is to move to `curl`?

Comment: I'd use a library for a [real http client](https://github.com/amphp/artax).

Comment: If we’re suggestion our personal favourite HTTP clients, then check out [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many great libraries that abstract `curl` handling problems from PHP. I personally like Guzzle and Request. You can find links to that libraries [here](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#http).

That being said, you do have a syntax error in your script, because `$context` is the third parameter of [`file_get_content()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

It should be:

```
$page = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

And you can pass [extra options to your `stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). By default it follows redirects, and 20 is the maximum number of redirects before giving up.

Are you sure that URL, when loaded in your browser, doesn't do redirects with JS?

Comment: Thanks for noting the error in my script. Corrected that in the OT. Regarding the JS redirect: I'm not sure but I think that I would get the raw HTML anyway?

Comment: Nope. If the redirect is done with JS, you won't get the HTML (because the redirect is performed in your browser and not with HTTP headers).

Comment: I meant that I will get the document containing the redirection JS code, not the final document.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong usage of file_get_contents():
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
third parameter should be $context